# What parts are compatible with the Anycubic Mega Zero? (FNG here)

Tags: fdm, anycubic-i3-mega

I bought a 3D printer 2nd hand from someone a year and a half ago and finally set it up last week (I know I'm terrible). It's an Anycubic Mega Zero. I'm pretty sure it's the first version not the 2.0 as it doesn't have a hotbed. My question is what aftermarket parts are compatible (preferably plug and play) with it?

I've searched the name and model and am not coming up with a straight answer. Is there a specific model or "type" I should look for to know it will be compatible? Or a place that's a good site to work off of other than Amazon that maybe they actually know when I ask a question?.

I'm mainly concerned with parts that I can just plug in and go with minimal setup or **very** good directions explained well. Feel free to add more advanced options also for consideration later such as dual head extruders and maybe an explanation on how to modify firmware (links if available).

[image]

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! What is FNG? Please explain if I'm missing something. Furthermore, the question is very vague. Which parts do you want to replace, or are there parts missing? Please add an image if so. Possible upgrades and options cause endless discussion and the world of answers. Please be specific what you want to replace and why. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Save the question by posting an image of the printer to aid in the selection of the correct printer name and type. Be specific with what you want to buy new. Or e.g. if you want to upgrade to a heated bed.

Comment: hey oscar thanks for the reply FNG is a slang term we use in my part of the US that in the nicest terms means freaking new guy lol and as far as specifics i think i would like a better hotend and a heated bed and maybe a better extruder ive seen dual z axis lead screws any input on the usefulness of that? like i said im super new some im just now figuring things out and im not even sure what the model is for my hotend but i did find some articles a minute ago that had some info on upgrading the hotend with some 3d printed parts so that maybe the way i go but first i gotta get nozzles and im

Comment: not really sure which ones to buy besides in terms of the end that screws into the hotend itself